# For loop in mips not working ? what could be problem?

Tags: mips

My Mips loop code not working. When i try to run this code this show me blank. what could be a problem.

```
.data
.text
.globl main
main:

li $t0,0

for:
ble $t0,5,end //for (int i=0;i<=5;i++)

li $v0,1
move $a0,$t0
syscall

add $t0,$t0,1
j for

end:

li $v0,10
syscall
```

Comment: You need to experiment with single step debugging.  If you had done that, you would see the control flow exit the loop on the first iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When hand compiling C/pseudo code, in particular if statements and the condition of for loops, remember that you usually want to jump "over" the code when the condition does not hold. In your example you have

```
//for (int i=0;i<=5;i++)
//{
//    ... some code
//}
```

so you want to jump over the for body when the condition is not met. Instead of branching when i is less than or equal to 5, you have to branch when its greater than 5.

You would then compile that for with this:

```
for:
 bgt $t0,5,end //for (int i=0;i<=5;i++)  so you use bgt instead of ble
  ...
 j for
end:
```